# clientHeight and scrollHeight calculation

Tags: javascript, html, dom, specifications

[image]

Having this DOM structure, I am trying to get dimensions of the outer `div` ($0).
The values I am getting are:

```
$0.getBoundingClientRect().height // 14.35
$0.clientHeight // 14
$0.scrollHeight // 15
```

while the inner `span` has `line-height` and `height` equal to 16.

According to MDN ([scrollHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight) and [clientHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight)) values are being rounded to an integer, but I was not able to find these rules in the [spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#dom-element-scrollheight).

Interesting thing here is that this behaviour is observed only on Windows (both Chrome and Firefox). Mac and Linux seems to be fine.

My questions are:

1. is there any explanation to this behaviour or it is a bug in implementation?
2. is there a way to get element scroll size (other than calculting all the children's dimensions).

Comment: 1. https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#ref-for-dom-element-scrollheight says it's a `long`. 2. What do you mean?

Comment: The rounding to `long` appears to be inconsistent for two values. Only on windows.  I am trying to understand is it supposed to be so, or something is wrong here.

Comment: @Kaiido the second question is simply a request to suggest a workaround =)